# setOnAction restrictions and datepicker class

Tags: date, javafx, datepicker

I'm writing an application involved in time difference, there is something I don't get it,

```
    final DatePicker datePick=new DatePicker();
    LocalDate time;
    Label label=new Label();
    datePick.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
            time=datePick.getValue();//doesn't work, must 'LocalDate time=datePick.getValue();
            label.setText(time);//doesn't work must label.setText("Time now:"+time)
        }
    });
```

It gives an error saying "Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively fine", anyway, all I did, declare 'time' variable inside setOnAction() and it worked, so what was wrong? and 'label.setText(time);' if I don't write some text inside, like 'label.setText("Time now: "+ time);' ,won't work too, that's weird, yet why?

Comment: Why not just do `label.setText(datePicekr.getValue());`?

Comment: please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html and other chapters on language basics @Sedrick think again <g> I know that you know the return type of picker.getValue :)

Comment: Sedrick, won't work

Comment: Thanks for the correction @kleopatra. I was tired and being lazy last night. I actually couldn't remember if `getValue()` returned a  `LocalDate` or returned a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Java restricts local variables you access from a anonymus class/lambda expression to those that never change their values after assignment (i.e. thoser the compiler wouldn't complain about, if you declared them as `final`). If you could write to the local variable from a anonymus class this would violate this condition. It's not possible to write to local variables of the containing method from anonymus classes for this reason.

You should declare variables in the scope where they are needed anyways.

As for `label.setText(time);`:

`Label.setText` is a method with a `String` parameter. Since `String` is not a supertype of `LocalDate`, a simple assignment won't work. You need to convert the date to a `String`. String concatenation does this automatically, i.e. the `+` operator receiving a `String s` as first operand and a `Object o` as second operand outputs the concatenation of `s` and `Objects.toString(o)`.

You could simply convert to string yourself:

```
label.setText(Objects.toString(time, ""));
```

Or use a more sophisticated method for convertion to string.